# no uniform with name 'u_proj' in shader

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, libgdx, glsl, shader

I wrote a pair of shaders to display the textures as greyscale instead of full color. I used these shaders with libGDX's built in SpriteBatch class and it worked. Then when I tried to use it with the built in SpriteCache class it didn't work. I looked at the SpriteCache code and saw that it set some different uniforms that I tried to take into account but I seem to have gone wrong somwhere.

The SpriteCache class in libGDX sets the following uniforms:

```
customShader.setUniformMatrix("u_proj", projectionMatrix);
customShader.setUniformMatrix("u_trans", transformMatrix);
customShader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", combinedMatrix);
customShader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_proj;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform mat4 u_trans;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = a_position* u_proj * u_trans;
}
```

and this is the fragment shader:

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform u_projTrans;
void main() {
        vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).rgba;
        float gray = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;
        vec3 grayscale = vec3(gray + 0* u_projTrans[0][0]);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(grayscale, color.a);
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no uniform with name 'u_proj' in shader
...
com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)ackends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

I guess do any of you guys know why this isn't working? There is a uniform with the name u_proj.
Thank you all!

Comment: Your shader is invalid, so it fails to compile. You get that error on `u_proj` only because it's the first thing you try to do to your invalid shader. See @Reto_Koradi's answer below for why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What Reto Koradi said was true I had forgotten to put a mat4 tag before u_projTrans, that helped me.

Then what Tenfour04 said was a huge help too! I hadn't known about:

```
if (!shader.isCompiled()) throw new GdxRuntimeException("Couldn't compile shader: " + shader.getLog());
```

---

What helped me most in the long run was finding that glsl, when compiling, would do away with unused imports and that if you weren't able to trick the compiler into thinking that unused imports were used being used the shader would compile and then crash on runtime.

In libgdx there is a static "pedantic" variable that you can set. If it is set to false the application won't crash if variables are sent to the shader that the shader isn't using, they will simply be ignored. The code in my libgdx program looked something like this:

```
ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
```

Thanks for your help all! I hope this can help someone in the future

Comment: The biggest issue and what really helped was the pedantic tag. I thought that it made more sense to post again including that than to accept his that way anyone could find out about it.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that you check the success of your shader compilation/linking. Your fragment shader will not compile:

```
uniform u_projTrans;
```

This variable declaration needs a type. It should be:

```
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
```

You can use the following calls to test for errors while setting up your shader programs:

```
glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, ...);
glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, ...);
glGetProgramiv(programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, ...);
glGetProgramInfoLog(programId, ...);
```

Comment: In libgdx, which OP is using, it is simpler to see the error by calling this right after creating the ShaderProgram: `if (!shader.isCompiled()) throw new GdxRuntimeException("Couldn't compile shader: " + shader.getLog());`